Having many sub-urls on the same custom taxonomy term
I have custom taxonomies, and each term has many URLs to display content like below:
/custom-taxo/term-1/slug-1
/custom-taxo/term-1/slug-2
/custom-taxo/term-1/slug-3

/custom-taxo/term-2/slug-1
/custom-taxo/term-2/slug-2
/custom-taxo/term-2/slug-3

The data/content for /custom-taxo/term-1/slug-1 and /custom-taxo/term-2/slug-1 have the same structure.
Would it be possible to override /wp-admin/term.php such that each taxonomy slug has its own edit page, e.g:
/wp-admin/term.php?taxonomy=custom-taxo&tag_ID=1&slug=slug-1&...
/wp-admin/term.php?taxonomy=custom-taxo&tag_ID=1&slug=slug-2&...

or should I create a custom edit page?
Ultimately I want to be able to have a RankMath SEO control on each edit page, as currently I can only have one RankMath control per page.
